# Gratis software to remove black bars from a movie

Tags: windows, gratis, video-editing

I'm looking for software that is able to remove black bars from a movie (the bars found within the top and bottom of a video). The software should meet these requirements,

- Compatible with Windows 10 64bit
- Gratis
- Able to input and output popular video formats such as .mp4
- Automatically detects black bars and strips them away

Comment: Aren't those black bars the result of "letterboxing" - displaying a wide/theatrical formatted film on a screen too narrow for it, resulting in vertical shrinkage?  What would you like to have happen: trimming off the sides?

Comment: @CPerkins Exactly, removal of the black bars by trimming off the sides

Comment: How's this?    http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjTi5r11pjMAhWEHD4KHc2kCYsQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.freemake.com%2Fblog%2Fhow-to-remove-black-bars-from-video%2F&usg=AFQjCNE9Ef7uF4n0MlX5Ke8P6yJnRiNOjg&bvm=bv.119745492,d.dmo

Comment: @CPerkins Xvid4PSP seems to meet this requirement, if you add it as an answer, I will try it later today and if it works, I'll up-vote and accept it.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that Xvid4PSP is in fact not suitable for you?  I'll delete my answer if that's the case, but it would be good to know how it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this myself - I'm just a googler here.

[Xvid4PSP](https://code.google.com/archive/p/xvid4psp/) seems to meet your requirements.

- it is gratis (GNU GPL v2)
- can detect black bars (add a video by clicking the Open button. When the video appears in the program, go to Video, select "Delete black borders")
- can export to MP4 (MP4 PSP AVC, MP4 PSP ASP, MP4 iPod, MP4 iPod 640, MP4 iPod Touch, MP4 iPhone, MP4 PS3, MP4 Xbox 360, MP4, and many more)

Comment: Downvoters: please give new users a chance and at least tell the OP what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Thomas.   I don't mind the downvote(s): if an answer isn't suitable, it's not suitable.

Comment: Glad to hear that you're already so cool about it. Took me some time to think like this.